# Query pages by child term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, query, terms

I cannot seem to get this to work, I have tried everything I can think of and spent enough time googling, to get me to seek help elsewhere.

I need to query pages in a loop, using the same taxonomy as the current page, but the child term of the current pages term.

For example,

```
taxonomy = walls
current page term = art

queried pages taxonomy = art
queried pages term= modern-art ( where art is the parent term of modern-art)
```

I can do this using

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page'
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order'=>'ASC',
  'tax_query'   => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'walls',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    =>  'modern-art'
       )
    )
```

However, I need this code to be dynamic and fetch the data. So I can use the same template of lots of different parent and child terms.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "dynamic" ? Do you want it to work with different posts?

If so, that's simple. Before your get_posts query function, get page terms, and pass them to your array. You can get taxonomies with

```
 <?php get_the_terms( $yourpostid, 'your_custom_taxonomy'); ?>
```

Comment: Or You can use ShortCode

Comment: Hi there, the idea is that I cannot use a set id ($yourpostid) because this has to be used on multiple pages. So by dynamic I mean that I can use this for different pages with different parent and child terms, if that makes any sense ? For example, still on the walls taxonomy, on another page with a post query, I may have another parent term 'design' with a child term 'modern-design' as opposed to 'art' and 'modern-art'.